# Xmlcatalog in Ant script to read part of XML tags

Tags: ant, xmltask, xmlcatalog

I have a xyz.html file which contains the line-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>I am Man (2.0)</title>
```

I need to extract the value (2.0). I can use xmltask and do it, but because of the

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

in the 1st line, xmltask is unable to do so. If I remove that line, it is correctly extracting the value. I found out that xmlcatalog can be used to bypass this. What will be the ant script to get this?

Edit:
I added these lines but this didn't help either:

```
<xmlcatalog>
<dtd 
        publicId="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        location="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>
</xmlcatalog>
```

Comment: You wrote "I found out that xmlcatalog can be used to bypass this" : can you elaborate what you found / where you found it ?

Comment: i was referring to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492676/xmltask-confused-about-dtd

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an http proxy in the way of ant resolving the dtd location  in this case ?

Comment: I'm not sure of that. Is my code alright? Or is something else required?